# How to add Root Node to the Tree Panel in extjs 4 mvc

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, extjs4, gant

I am having the tree with all my task which gets all the data from the database and i am able to display the data in the treeview panel.

Now **I want to add Root node dynamically. ie. user when clicks the Add New Root Node button**, I am able to create new Root in the Tree view panel.

I am able to create Child of the existing root panel but not the new Parent.

My code to add child to the already existing root node is

```
 text: 'Add new Root Node',
                iconCls: 'icon-save',
                handler: function () {
                    var task = taskStore.getRootNode().findChild('Name', 'Parent 1');

                    if(task) {
                        task.insertChild(0, new taskStore.model({
                            Name: 'Added as first child!',
                            PercentDone: 60,
                            StartDate : new Date(2010, 0, 6),
                            EndDate : new Date(2010, 0, 8)
                        })
                        );
                    }
                }
```

**when I click on it everything is fine, but I want to create a New Root Node.
So what I had to change to my things happen.**

Your's sincerely
Yogendra Singh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have more than one root. You can hide root node by setting `rootVisible` to `false`, to simulate such behaviour.
[Here](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.0/examples/tree/treegrid.html) is example.

Comment: thanks for your reply.. I am able to solve my problem by using below code taskStore.getRootNode().appendChild(...)